# HTML/CSS problems table display

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to find a way to have one table with 4 rows having exactly the same height (without using table tag). This table is included in a `div` that has `table-cell` display.

I created this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jejupogodi/edit?html,output

I want that the pink part to take all the available height and each row inside it should have 25% of the height (whatever the content length is).

Comment: Could you please edit your title to be a little bit more descriptive as well as elaborate your question a little bit more?

Comment: http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways

Comment: Your code is a bit messy and hard to follow. For your own benefit, you may want to consider cleaning it up for future maintenance.

Comment: this is just for jsbin/jsfiddle.... I'm using jquery templating so there's really not much html in fact. But reproducing it in jsbin/jsfiddle is a pain. This is why I hardcoded the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tidied up your code a bit. I used `vh` (vertical height) instead of percentage. You can run the code snippet but here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eznkmasa/4/)

```css
    .container {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: lightgreen;
    }
    .focus {
      height: 500px;
    }
    .sliderContainer {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 40%;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: top;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .slider {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .slider li {
      display: table-row;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 25vh;
      background-color: pink;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    li .sliderImg{min-height:5vh; max-height:5vh;}
    .sliderDetails {
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      min-height: 20vh;
      max-height:20vh;

      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="focus">
      <div>
        <div class="focusDetails">
          <div class="focusTitle"></div>
          <div class="focusDesc"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="previous" style="display:none;"><span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="next"><span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderContainer">
      <ul class="slider">
        <li>
          <div class="sliderImg"></div>
          <div class="sliderDetails">

            <p class="sliderTitle">Town Hall Meeting Presentation - Sunstar Italiana</p>
            <p class="sliderDesc">On Tuesday, June 30 all Sunstar Italiana employees took part to the Town Hall Meeting presentation made by the General Manager, Marco Bruscaini. Through his</p>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="sliderImg"></div>
          <div class="sliderDetails">

            <p class="sliderTitle">Top Management Visits the HQ in Etoy</p>
            <p class="sliderDesc">The welcome to the Sunstar Headquarter June Meetings' attendees from Asia, Japan, and the US was done as a tour to the Sunstar Campus' two buildings, the new and previous one The welcome to the Sunstar Headquarter June Meetings' attendees
              from Asia, Japan, and the US was done as a tour to the Sunstar Campus' two buildings, the new and previous one</p>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="sliderImg"></div>
          <div class="sliderDetails">
            <p class="sliderTitle">Distributor meeting</p>
            <p class="sliderDesc">For the 3rd year we have organized our Distributor meeting taking place this time in our new building in Etoy, Switzerland.This year, we decided to extend our invitation to all the</p>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="sliderImg"></div>
          <div class="sliderDetails">
            <p class="sliderTitle">Distributor meeting</p>
            <p class="sliderDesc">For the 3rd year we have organized our Distributor meeting taking place this time in our new building in Etoy, Switzerland.This year, we decided to extend our invitation to all the</p>

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: wow thanks! I never used this vh.... didn't even know it exists :-D. Just learned something.

Comment: @PlaTyPuS you should put 100vh in your container to make it even aswell http://jsfiddle.net/eznkmasa/1/ Always good to learn!

Comment: but even with 100vh in the container the LI don't have the same height. If I put 20vh (in place of 25vh), then it seems to work better but I don't understand why.

Comment: it's because you have a div for your slider img. if you pit in .sliderImg{max-height:7vh;} or something that should sort it out

Comment: oh, ok! last question, why does it not resize if I set the height of .container to 500px?

Comment: cos vh goes on browser size and would override the pixel thing. if you want to use pixels go back to % vh is more responsive i think

Answer (score 0):

Solved by flexbox.
https://jsbin.com/yutucapuze/1/edit?output

```css
/* **************
   Quick Reset
************** */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
/* **********
   Style
********** */
.Rows {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -o-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-lines: single;
  -moz-box-lines: single;
  -o-box-lines: single;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.Row {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -o-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 500px;
}
.Slider {
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}
.Slider:after {
  content: '50% width & 500px heigth';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #3da7b4;
}
.List {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.Item {
  display: block;
  min-height: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  max-height: 25%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #555;
}
.Item:after {
  content: '25% heigth';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #3da7b4;
}
.Item__content {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
```

```html
<div class="Rows">
  <div class="Row Slider"></div>
  <div class="Row List">
    <div class="Item">
      <p class="Item__content">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
      <p class="Item__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni illum fugiat velit a laborum harum molestias</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
      <p class="Item__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni illum fugiat velit a laborum harum molestias saepe hic rerum. Aut omnis voluptatum placeat, amet aliquam, alias voluptatibus fugiat beatae quibusdam?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
      <p class="Item__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni illum fugiat velit a laborum harum molestias saepe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I also thought of doing it with flexbox. But as I really need a IE9 compatibility...I cannot use it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox